# Selecting from across multiple tables in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

Say I have Apples, Oranges and Melons, and each has a column "created_at".  How would I construct an ActiveRecord / SQL query to find the 10 most recent Apples, Oranges and Melons?  Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: Are these distinct types - i.e. do you have an Apple, Orange and Melon class, or do you have a single Fruit class with a fruit_name attribute?

Answer (score 2):

If you have those types in separate tables, then I don't think you can do that in a single SQL query.

You can find ids and types of the most recent records like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT 'Apple' AS class, id, created_at FROM apples LIMIT 10
UNION
SELECT 'Orange' AS class, id, created_at FROM oranges LIMIT 10
UNION
SELECT 'Melon' AS class, id, created_at FROM melons LIMIT 10) AS most_recent
ORDER BY created_at
LIMIT 10;
```

Then use these records to fetch particular objects by id.

But if you can, try to store all these in a single table using Single Table Inheritance pattern, which is [built-in into rails](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html). This would work OK if the types shared a lot of fields. Then you could just use a single Fruit.find call with `order` and `limit` to fetch what you want.

In Rails 2:

```
Fruit.find(:all, :order => "created_at", :limit => 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but this should work

```
Apples.joins(:oranges).joins(:melons).order("apples.created_at,oranges.created_at,melons.created_at DESC").limit(10)
```